# Why am I unable to alphabetically sort a multidimensional array in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, cocoa, multidimensional-array

I have a question concerning sorting of a multidimensional array. The array holds `n` elements, each element has three objects, an `NSString`, an `NSNumber`, and another `NSString`. The two objects, the `NSNumber` and the second string need to stay with the first string in an array but I need to alphabetize the array by the first string.

I previously used the following code to alphabetize a single element array:

```objc
theSortedFilenames = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[filenamesArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

However, a version of that code modified to alphabetize the bigger multidimensional array by the first object’s name does not work:

```objc
theSortedFilenames = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[elementsArray[0] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

I also tried:

```
NSComparisonResult alphaSort(NSString *string1, NSString *string2, void *context)
{
    return [string1 caseInsensitiveCompare:string2];
}

// sort things
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [elementsArray[0] sortedArrayUsingFunction:alphaSort context:NULL];
```

Which didn’t work and also a variant given in an answer to a previous question here on stack overflow:

```
static NSInteger order (id a, id b, void* context) {
    NSString* catA = [a firstObject];
    NSString* catB = [b firstObject];
    return [catA caseInsensitiveCompare:catB];
}

sortedArray = [theArrayToSort sortedArrayUsingFunction:order context:self];
```

Which also did not work. Can anyone suggest a way to alphabetize the array of three object elements by the first element while maintaining the relationship between all three objects?

Comment: Could you provide some sample of the input data to be sorted?

Comment: int i;
NSString *arg1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"String1"];
NSNumber *arg2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSString *arg3 = [NSString stringWithString:@"String2"];
NSArray *arrayElement = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:arg1, arg2, arg3, nil];
NSArray *arrayToSort = [NSArray arrayWithObject:arrayElement];
for (i = 0; i  < 99; i++) {
 [arrayToSort addObject:arrayElement];
}
// arrayToSort now has 101 arrayElements in it
// I want arrayToSort to be sorted alphabetically on the characters in arg1

Comment: The second `sortedArrayUsingFunction` should work. How did it not work?

Comment: Edit your question with input value and desired output, it should be clearer.

Comment: Your last attempt should work: `NSMutableArray *arrayToSort = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; for (NSInteger i = 5; i > 0; i--)  [arrayToSort addObject:@[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"String1-%d", i], @(i), [NSString stringWithFormat:@"String2-%d", i]]];} NSArray *sorted = [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSArray * _Nonnull obj1, NSArray *  _Nonnull obj2) { return [[obj1 firstObject] caseInsensitiveCompare:[obj2 firstObject]]; }]; NSLog(@"Sorted: %@", sorted); NSArray *sorted2 = [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingFunction:order context:NULL]; NSLog(@"Sorted2: %@", sorted2);`

Comment: Well, I finally got it to work! I really didn't understand how sortedArrayUsingFunction:order worked. Thank you Larme for insisting it would. I spent a lot more time studying how it does work and came up with an approach that works. I'm very grateful to Larme for causing me to try that approach again. Thanks to all for helping with this, it turned out more difficult than I originally thought but now it works perfectly. Sorry about the formatting of the question and response, the web site seems not to be cooperating as it should. Thanks again.